# How to disable SpeedStep for an Intel Core i7 processor?

Tags: intel-core-i7, speedstep

I'm taking performance measurements of several bits of code. **How can I disable SpeedStep on my Core i7 CPU so that the CPU clock speed is constant?**  I'm not trying to overclock here, and since SpeedStep only throttles up when it's safe (given the CPU temperature) to do so, I expect turning off SpeedStep will throttle it down to the minimum.  That's fine.  I just need it constant.

Setting power options to High Performance does *not* disable SpeedStep.

I am using a Dell Studio 1558 if that's relevant.

Comment: +1 I would love to know if this shows any differences in measurements.

Comment: What programming language are you using?  If it's a compiled language, you may want to get the x86 assembly and just count the number of instructions/clock cycles to compare function efficiency.  That, and you won't be relying on timers or other system applications interrupting the run-time of your program...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will vary from board to board, but there should be an explicit BIOS option for "Intel SpeedStep" or "EIST" that you can disable.

EDIT: Also, I believe you have it backwards.  SpeedStep is responsible for downthrottling, not upthrottling; you'll run at the base clockspeed if you turn it off.  Turbo Boost is what upthrottles (but I believe SpeedStep does have to be on for that to work).

DOUBLEEDIT: You shouldn't need to, but you can also try disabling C1E support.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, there should be a BIOS option that might or might not effect the clock throttling.

If the BIOS option doesn't exist and no BIOS firmware allows you to change this, it seems like a no-go...

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Vista or Windows 7 try setting the power plan to "High Performance."  The resource monitor (Computer Management in Vista, stand-alone app in 7) will confirm that the CPU speed is constant.

In addition to SpeedStep though you should probably also disable the Core i7's turbo mode, which probably needs to be done in the BIOS.

Answer (score -1):

If you run Win XP/Vista/7 install the program Throttlestop from [Techpowerup](https://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/2288/throttlestop-6-00/) which "contains a variety of options which can be used to bypass CPU throttling" and currently supports up to Intel 4th Generation Core (Haswell).

- When you have opened up the program uncheck EIST (Enhanced Intel SpeedStep) that dynamically increases/decreases CPU clock speed between minimum clock and normal operating frequency, as well as voltage, in order to optimize for power consumption.
- Keep throttlestop open

Comment: Your post needs to be expanded. A good [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) includes specific instructions (not just links to them) and an explanation as to how or why the answer addresses the OPs question.  Please edit your post to adequately address both of these elements.

Comment: @Twisty my answer is the best and the only valid answer even though he marked another reply as answer. nobody in this thread knows the solution. if you dont  like my answer, just delete it. the viewer will just google and download throttlestop. and uncheck a button. it's simple.

Comment: For example, can you explain what the EIST option does? You could also provide a link to the program you are recommending and a basic description of what it does. These edits will make your answer easy to use for future visitors. Thanks for contributing on Super User.